# ¿Como recibir datos de LOCALSTORAGE enviados por AJAX a mi servidor PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, servidor

Es mi primera pregunta espero su ayuda.

Tengo este código en mi servidor para recibir los datos que provienen de mi `ajax` que saco de un almacenamiento `Localstorage`, para este ejemplo solo hay una variable la cual quisiera que no solo se escriba en el documento **your_data.txt** que lo hace `file_put_contents` sino que en el momento de llegar la información, el `PHP` maneje esa información y la almacene en bd `MySQL` o que me la envíe por `email`, por favor ayuda :(

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
    echo '<h2>Server Timezone : ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '</h2>';
    $current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s ');
    print "<h2>Server Time : " . $current_date . "</h2>";
    $dataObject = $_POST['data'];

    $json = json_decode($dataObject,true);
      file_put_contents('your_data.txt)', $json);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function to generate random str as key for the localStorage
function randomStr(m) {
        var m = m || 9; s = '', r = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        for (var i=0; i < m; i++) { s += r.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*r.length)); }
        return s;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
var hasStorage = true;
localStorage.clear();
if(!localStorage.getItem("names")) {
var hasStorage = (function() {
try {
var myRSSObject = new Object();
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(myRSSObject));
return true;
} catch(e) {
return false;
}
}());
}
$("#submit").click(function() {
if(hasStorage) {
var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));
names[randomStr(7)] = document.getElementById("name").value;
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify( names ));
alert("Stored Succesfully");
document.getElementById("name").value = "";
alert("Now Passing stored data to Server through AJAX jQuery");
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://tiendaseguras.net/php7/end.php",
data: {data: localStorage.getItem("names")},
dataType : 'json',
success : function(response){
alert("funciona bien");
},
error: function(error){
alert("No funciona");
}
});
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Add Name for Storing" id="name">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
<div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Mi servidor recibe con este `PHP`, solo me guarda en un `txt`.